# Access Denied (Service: ; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I wrote a lambda function that accesses and reads a file in the S3 storage of the same region. The code is the following in scala

```scala
   val bucketName = "***myBucketName***"
    val fileName = "input.log"
    val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()
    val myObject = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName))
    val inputStream = myObject.getObjectContent()
    val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
```

I deploy it on AWS via SAM-cli
When I run it locally it can access the file, but when I run it on AWS
It throws

```
Access Denied (Service: ; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied
```

Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Your Lambda function gets its permissions from an IAM role. When you run things locally, you are presumably using IAM User credentials.

Comment: What's the difference and how can I solve this issue in your opinion?

Comment: When you created the Lambda function, you supplied an IAM role. Make sure the policies associated with the role are sufficient for the Lambda function to operate, specifically wrt S3. These are well documented.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you have to check the permission given to the lambda role. This page explains how to get to the lambda role: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Once you know the role, you can manually check the permissions to make sure that `s3:GetObject` is there. You can also assume it locally and try to read the object from the CLI to make sure the permissions are all right: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Lastly, mind that, if the bucket is encrypted, you'll need to modify the KMS policy to grant the role permission to use it and to decrypt. Similarly, you might need to modify the bucket policy to allow the role to perform a `s3:GetObject` operation.